# Typescript complains that it cannot assign string to conditional type `T extends ? string: null`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

So, I am pretty stumped with what seems to be a trivial example.
I was testing out conditional types based on the blog post [here](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/) and I cannot get the snippet to compile. I do not understand what I am doing wrong

```js
function processO< T extends string | null>(test: T): T extends string ? string : null {
    return test && test.replace(/f/g, "p")
}

processO("foo").toUpperCase()
```

This is the error from Typescript

```
a.ts:2:5 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : null'.

2     return test && test.replace(/f/g, "p")
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is `string` not being capable of being assigned to `T extends string ? string : null`. Am I missing a `declare` block or an overload ?

**EDIT**: Looks like this is a well known limitation and documention with alternatives provided [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929)

Comment: Were you following [this example](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/)? Anyway, the fourth comment on that article is complaining about the same problem.

Comment: You are right. Looks like this is a well-know [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929). Looks like a code-snippet that sort of (in the author's defense, the actual implementation was left out as `...` in the post) didn't work.

Comment: When I am using a conditional as a return type I usually end up having to use `as` in the function return so that the function knows that it matches its signature.  It's annoying but yeah it's a common issue.